# how to access all pixels between 2 non linear points on an image

Tags: c++, opencv, line, pixel

I am trying to access all the pixels between 2 non linear points. But I could not do it. 
To say it simple, with function cvLine i draw a line between two points, as shown in image the image below (I want to access the pixels along green line between 2 red points).

[image]

I tried the following:

```
Rect myROI(midPx, midPy, (edgPx-midPx), (midPy-edgPy)+1);    
Mat croppedImage = mask(myROI);
```

It doesn't work in my case.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

I am sorry, actually i tried the same as in example, it was mistake while commenting. I tried both the methods from the example;

```
LineIterator it(mask, Point(midPx, midPy), Point(edgPx, edgPy), 8);
LineIterator it2 = it;
vector<Vec3b> buf(it.count);
//cout << buf<< endl;
for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
{
    buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;
}

// alternative way of iterating through the line
//for(int i = 0; i < it2.count; i++, ++it2)
 //{
   // cout <<it2.pos()<<","<<val<< endl;
    //buf.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,0)) = val;
//}
imshow("buf Image", buf);
```

but left with error at buf[i]

```
erreur: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>(((const unsigned char*)it.cv::LineIterator::operator*()))
```

Comment: `It doesn't work in my case.` - what doesn't work, what are the errors?

Comment: using Rect is not a good choice as it considers all the pixels inside the rectangle between 2 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out LineIterator, which is used to get each pixel of a line and allows you to process them: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator

Small example (based on the link):

```
// grabs pixels along the line (pt1, pt2)
// from 8-bit 3-channel image to the buffer
LineIterator it(img, pt1, pt2);
vector<Vec3b> buf(it.count);

// iterate through the line
for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
    buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;
```

Comment: thanks for the link and sample code, this seems really good idea, but when i tried i receive an error at   "  buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it; " saying 
                                                                                                               "erreur: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>(((const unsigned char*)it.cv::LineIterator::operator*())) "

Comment: Your code is a little different from the example (  `buf[i] = (const Vec3b)*it;` instead of `buf[i] = *(const Vec3b)*it;` ). If the issue remains, try to post your code so it's easier to help you.

Comment: In your code you have `buf(i)` instead of `buf[i]`, maybe that's the reason? Try to edit your original post with the code since you create the `cv::Mat` until you get the error

Comment: I am sorry, actually i tried the same as in example, it was mistake while commenting. I tried both the methods from the example;  `for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it) {  buf(i) = *(const Vec3b)*it; } > // for(int i = 0; i < it2.count; i++, ++it2)  {  // Vec3b val = mask.at<Vec3b>(it2.pos()); // cout <<it2.pos()<<","<<val<< endl; // CV_Assert(buf[i] == val);  }  imshow("buf Image", buf);`  but its the same error  `erreur: no match for ‘operator’ in ‘cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>(((const unsigned char)it.cv::LineIterator::operator*()))`

Comment: Alright, try to change the for loop to this:

`for(int i=0; i<it.count; i++)
{
    buf.push_back( Vec3b(*it) );
    it++;
}`

Comment: hei, thanks for this help, this actually works well, but the only issue is, the total number of pixels increased by 2x times, i.e first half of the pixel row are black pixels(extra and unwanted) and required pixels starts from second half till end. But it is not a problem for me as i can consider from second half.  Anyways thanks again